# How to use getComputedStyle with DOMParser produced document (no defaultView or window objects)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, gecko

I have this code (simplified):

```
var s = '<div>html...</div>';  
var parser = new DOMParser();  
var doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
```

The resulting document object does not have a defaultView nor a window properties, so is there a way to call getComputedStyle() ?

To explain more: I use code like this in a Firefox extension that performs batch DOM manipulation on HTML files and serializes then writes the modified documents back to disk.

As pointed out by Mike, there is a hiddenDOMWindow, so I adapted his code to something like this:

```
const { Services } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var s = '<div style="color:red;font-family:Tahoma">html...</div>';  
var parser = new DOMParser();  
var doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');  
var div = doc.querySelector("div");
var win = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow;

var div2 = win.document.importNode(div, true);
var style = win.getComputedStyle(div2);
alert( style.getPropertyValue('color') ); //alerts rgb(255, 0, 0) which is correct!
```

Thanks Mike, I never knew there was a hiddenDOMWindow.

Comment: Thanks Mike, while your code works with no errors, it does not work! the returned CSSStyleDeclaration object had all property values set to defaults. But it gave me the pointer i needed so I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work from either content or an extension:

```
var s = '<div>html...</div>';  
var parser = new DOMParser();  
var doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');  
var div = doc.querySelector("div");

var style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
```

If you don't have access to a window e.g. from an extension then you could do it this way:

```
const { Services } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var s = '<div>html...</div>';  
var parser = new DOMParser();  
var doc = parser.parseFromString(s, 'text/html');  
var div = doc.querySelector("div");
var win = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow;

var style = win.getComputedStyle(div);
```

Comment: This wont work. Computed Style will only work with elements that were added to the window document.
Although you can call the method and get a response, the styles wont be the correct ones, but the default ones for each tag.